# ZF2 Move code from module.config.php to module.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've found on the web a way to declare a custom Navigation Menu using the following:

`module.config.php` in `Acl` module:

```
'navigation_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'menu' => 'Acl\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu',
    )
),
```

Now I'd like to pass a parameter to the custom `Menu` constructor. I'm quite new in ZF2 world but it seems that I have to create some kind of service in the `module.php` file. I've tried to put code into `getServiceConfig` and `getViewHelperConfig` methods without success (the custom menu is not "used").

Any idea/hint of the array structure and the method I should use?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you should register your menu as a factory and then you can pass parameters to the menu when instantiating the class inside the factory:

Create a `MenuFactory` class:

```
<?php

namespace Acl\View\Helper\Navigation\Factory;

/**
 * Factory to create menu
 */
class MenuFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $param = // get your param from servicelocator or create the parameter
        $menu = new Menu($param);
        return $menu;
    }
}
```

Now you register your menu as a **factory** instead of as an **invokable**:

```
'navigation_helpers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'menu' => 'Acl\View\Helper\Navigation\Factory\MenuFactory',
    )
),
```

If you want to read more then there is lot's of information on how to do this in ZF2 for example in **[this article here](http://blog.alejandrocelaya.com/2014/10/09/advanced-usage-of-service-manager-in-zend-framework-2/)**

Comment: Thanks, it works (even if I was looking for an easier solution)

Comment: @DavidL This might look maybe complicated but it is the ZF2 way to do it. You will see when you get more familiar with ZF2 that this is a common solution. I fixed a mistake in the config array...